# How can I easily inspect the html returned for the mobile version of my MVC site?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, mobile

I've just begun working with MVC 4 for the first time and have a simple site that has a separate desktop and mobile version of several views. I have always used Page Inspector or my desktop browsers to examine and work with the html source that I get back from the webserver. I'm using Electric Plum to test my site on Safari in the iPhone/iPad emulator (I don't see that you can get a view of the html source from the emulator). So I need a new browser, a new emulator, or way to trick the webserver with one of my current browsers so that I can easily work with the html I'm getting back for my mobile views. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can try [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en) on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Mac:

- open your site on the iPhone/iPad on Safari app
- connect your iPhone/iPad via USB
- enable the developer mode in Settings > Safari > Advanced
- open Safari on your laptop
- in the top bar, go into Development > Phone's name > page's name

The Safari Web Inspector is opened and lets you inspect all your dom elements and even alter them from your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox you can select Tools > Web Developer > Responsive Design View (CTRL + SHIFT + M).

Comment: That is a cool feature of Firefox I had not seen, but it is not sufficient for getting the webserver to return the mobile html (just shows how my desktop version of html would look under different size constraints).